# Drupal 7 Error for Invalid Tokens when enabling Visitos for Registration Page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to allow Visitors to register my site.

I have enabled both the modules `token` and `entity token`.

For that I have done following in my drupal 7 site.

- List item
- Go to URL: http ://my-site-url/admin/config/people/accounts
- Change REGISTRATION AND CANCELLATION Options
- Who can register accounts?

> 1 Administrators only
>
> 2 **Visitors** ( **Checked** )
>
> 3 Visitors, but administrator approval is required Checkbox Checked
>   for Email Verification.

Then, Click <**Save**> Button.

I have following error given while `updating the admin/config/people/accounts` Settings.

```
The Subject is using the following invalid tokens: [site:name].
The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [user:one-time-login-url], [site:name], [site:login-url].
The Subject is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
The Subject is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [user:one-time-login-url], [site:name], [site:login-url].
The Subject is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [user:one-time-login-url], [site:name].
The Subject is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [user:one-time-login-url], [site:name], [site:login-url].
The Subject is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
The Subject is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [user:cancel-url], [site:name], [site:url-brief].
The Subject is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name], [site:name].
```

I don't understand why this error given me at the time of update settings.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. how did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the account settings screen, there are a group of email templates so you can configure all the various emails the system will send for various user account actions ("Account Activation," "Account blocked, etc). They all use tokens in their body, subject, etc, and those tokens are for some reason coming up as invalid.

Check your Site Information config (`admin/config/system/site-information`) and make sure the relevant fields are filled in properly. Or, for a quick and dirty solution, edit the templates, remove the tokens, and replace with your site's equivalents. But it's better to make sure those tokens all have valid values.